# Use HTML formatting in SVG for text alignment

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make the numbers in this code line up regardless if they are positive or negative.

```js
pointer_labels = ["PANTS", "SOCKS", "SHOES"]
vals = [0, 0.8, -0.2]

var svg = d3.select("#root").append("svg")
var texts = svg.selectAll("text").data(pointer_labels);

texts.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 20 + 9;
  })
  .html(function(d, i) {
    var sign = '<foreignObject x="20" y="9" width="150" height="200">&nbsp;<span>&plus</span></foreignObject>';
    if (vals[i] < 0) {
      sign = "&nbsp;&minus;";
    }
    return pointer_labels[i] + " " + sign + Math.abs(vals[i]).toFixed(2);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

I'm trying to accomplish this by inserting an invisible minus sign, but whenever I insert an HTML tag, the text isn't displayed, despite being inserted into the DOM. I've reviewed the questions similar to this one and have tried the `foreignObject` trick, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Note that the reason I'm using SVG despite the fact that I seem only to be working with text, is that this is actually for plot legends that I'm making. This is how it looks in the actual application:
[image]

Comment: Even if the "invisible minus sign" works, they still won't align because the text before numbers can have different length. Since all the numbers are `toFixed(2)`, why not create another `text` element, and then right-align them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gildor's comment, I figured out that if I just created a separate text element for the numbers and align it to the right, I get the same effect.

```js
pointer_labels = ["PANTS", "SOCKS", "SHOES"]
vals = [0, 0.8, -0.2]

var svg = d3.select("#root").append("svg")
var texts = svg.selectAll("g").data(pointer_labels);

var txt_enter = texts.enter();

txt_enter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20 + 9;})
  .text(function(d, i) { return pointer_labels[i]});
txt_enter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 300)
    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20 + 9;})
    .attr("text-anchor","end")
  .html(function(d, i) {
                var sign = '';
                if(vals[i] < 0){
                    sign = "&minus;";
                }
                return sign + Math.abs(vals[i]).toFixed(2);
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Basically, if you can avoid using html inside SVG, you should.